# Price as a function of load on an electric grid(City modeling)

Tags: math, modeling

Thanks for your time. First some context and the actual question is marked further down.

**Context:**

I am modeling a city as a complex adaptive system and am building a model of an electric grid to run in parallel. The city model is focused on traffic/flow of people and the trade-off between public(bus) and personal(car: gas, electric).

The electric model is very simple and is meant to augment the city model. It has a tree structure where the leaf nodes are buildings and chargers for cars, the root node is a connection to an infinite power source outside the city, and the layers between are just connectors which I call substations.

Each node has a base draw and an extra draw per unit(car charging, person in building, ...) the draw of a parent node is added to by the draw of its children.

Each line will have a capacity and i wish to base the global price of electricity on the total load at the root node(with modifiers for overloads etc). So here is the question:

**Question:**

Is there a mathematical function used to calculate the price of electric power based on load that is used in the real world that I could use/adapt in my model?

If not, I was thinking the function would be an exponential which is fairly flat until an interval of optimal power load, increase sharply towards the end of the interval and explode after. See image.

[image]

*The image Depicts an exponential function Price(Load) where there are 3 intervals delineated by 2 values, a and b. The yellow interval (-inf < load < a) is below the optimal load, the green interval (a < load < b) is the optimal load and the red interval (b < load < inf) is above safe capacity*

Would this be a reasonable function for the pricing in a grid?
How would such a function look mathematically? I need to have *a* and *b* as variables in the equation for experiments and autonomous adaptation during the runs.

Any feedback on the model structure is also welcome.

Comment: Hi and first of all welcome to the Math.SE. Just an observation: I am not sure if there are more complex/precise pricing  functions for your problem. However, your idea to use an exponential model is fine since *power consumption is proportional to the number of users* so the price increases proportionally to the number of users, and thus to the current price.

Comment: I don't think you will find a universally applicable model. Utility companies also have to recover the costs of maintenance and just running a business, which are relatively constant. Sometimes rates vary with the time of day, or when a generation plant switches to a different kind of fuel. Utilities are also regulated by law, which may lead to pricing structures that are not intuitive.